# Exim filter - Matching FROM and TO

Tags: exim, filter

I have been receiving a lot of mailer-daemon spam lately ... It's obvious the spammer is spoofing the to & from fields so that mailer-daemon kicks in and delivers the actual message to me.

I created a filter which should discard the message but it doesn't work.  What is wrong with this?

```
if ("$h_to:" contains "$h_from:") 
then 
  seen finish 
endif
```

Example: 
From: me@domain.com To: me@domain.com  should be discarded, thus stopping the spam, but it still gets through. What can I do? Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Try not to use quotation marks. *if $h_to: contains $h_from: then*

Answer (score 0):

### Use preamble and remove `:`

- Add `# Exim filter` preamble <sup>[1](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SEC17)</sup>
- Remove extraneous colons (`:`)
- Double quotes (`"`) not necessary here

  - *see examples near https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SECTfilterstringexpansion*

#### Example

```
# Exim filter

if $h_from is $h_to then
    save $home/mail/SPAM
endif
```